# Vertical Align and Same Height using display table

Tags: css

I wish to have each li the same height and then display the ing centred (vertically).

http://jsfiddle.net/Lr7CU/

I've looked into display table cell but this fails to work for me.

I put

```
 display: table
```

On the UL

and

```
display: table-cell
```

On the LI

but no luck.

Comment: There's no mention to `display: table` or `display: table-cell` in your jsFiddle example.

Comment: Yes because I left a vanilla example.

Comment: What `vanilla` are you talking about?

Comment: LOL vanilla....what is this hentai? My suggestion is put it back to your table css request...so you just need them to be the same size and align to each other?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `diplay: table` on the ul, and `display :table-cell` on the li, you can set the `vertical-align: middle` to the li, and it will work. But you have to remove the `float: left`.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr7CU/2/

Comment: This answer is for the vertical align issue. The 5+ `<li>` problem is due to the `width: 20%` you applied to the li.

Comment: So how do I get more li's in, they are supposed to go t next line, hence float left, so your solution does not work.

Comment: His solution indeed works how many other lis do you expect on the same line? with your 20% as stated will of course go to the next line...